# Looking for Windows XP "dual desktops" with dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop, taskbar

I'm looking for some very specific features in a dual-monitor setup on Windows XP and so far have not been able to find what I'm looking for. The best way I can describe it is perhaps dual desktops or even virtual desktops displaying at the same time across two monitors. Ideally, I would like to have:

- Separate taskbar on each monitor (like MultiMon, UltraMon, etc.)
- The actual task buttons on the taskbar only show the apps open in that monitor (also like MultiMon, etc.)
- Each taskbar with a Start button, quicklaunch toolbar, and tray/clock. (can't find this anywhere!) These would be mirrors of each other, but for example running an app from the left monitor Start menu would open the app in the left monitor, maximizing from tray would do the same thing.
- Still able to drag windows/files/etc., do copy/paste, etc. from one window to another. (in other words something like a VM or remote desktop maximized in the other window wouldn't do it)

Does anyone know if such a setup is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Dexpot](http://www.dexpot.de/index.php?lang=en) is a Windows-based utility for Virtual Desktops, take a look at it and see if this will assist you in what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need a full shell replacement to do that. Explorer, which is the process that creates your start menu and desktop, does not have that functionality natively that I know of.

I would start with SharpE and see if it gives you the functionality you need: http://www.sharpenviro.com/wp/